# Coloring and showing edges of polygons from 2 files in GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot, polygon

I usually code in Python and do not know any GNUplot but I have to use a small bit of C to plot human cells represented as polygons. I have a file with all the coordinates of the polygon vertices at each time (it is a dynamic simulation), what the code does (and I don't know how) is that it links each cell vertex to form a cell edge and so we can see the different cells. Here is the code used to plot my polygons, the code I was given.

```
start = 0000
stop = 49990

set terminal pngcairo rounded size 800,800
set style line 1 lt 3 lc rgb pt 7 lw 2


set xrange [0:d*sqrt(N)]
set yrange [0:h*sqrt(N)]

point_files(n) = sprintf('./PointFiles/points%06d.txt', n)
cell_files(n) = sprintf('./CellpopFiles/cells%06d.txt', n)

do for [i = start:stop:10] {
    outfile = sprintf('./Figures/figures%06d.png',i)
    set output outfile
    unset key
    plot  cell_files(i) w filledcurves ls 1
}
```

So far the code works but then, I want to separate my cell population in 2 and color the two populations in 2 different colors, that's what I haven't managed. Only one of my cells are colored and even then the cell edges are not shown - I have white (instead of green) and red surfaces moving around but I can't see the limit between each cell, there is no edge.

```
start = 0000
stop = 49990

set terminal pngcairo rounded size 800,800
set style line 1 lt 3 lc rgb 'red' pt 7 lw 2
set style line 2 lt 3 lc rgb 'green' pt 7 lw 2

set xrange [0:d*sqrt(N)]
set yrange [0:h*sqrt(N)]

point_files(n) = sprintf('./PointFiles/points%06d.txt', n)
cell_files0(n) = sprintf('./Cellpop0Files/cells%06d.txt', n)
cell_files1(n) = sprintf('./Cellpop1Files/cells%06d.txt', n)

do for [i = start:stop:10] {
    outfile = sprintf('./Figures/figures%06d.png',i)    
    set output outfile
    unset key
    plot  cell_files0(i) w filledcurves ls 1
    plot  cell_files1(i) w filledcurves ls 2
}
```

Using 'w filledcurves closed ls 1' does not change anything.

The solution might be pretty simple but without knowing any C I've been struggling, thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume the code you show us is pseudo-code? Because it isn't C.

Comment: Yeah, it's not C.  Is it actually gnuplot?  What are you specifically doing to the compile it?

Comment: Yep sorry it's GNUplot, I thought GNU was just based on C and so it was the same... What do you mean "to compile it"? I have two files with the coordinates of my polygons Cellpop0Files and Cellpop1Files. I want to plot both of those on the same figure because they 'coincide' (they're all stuck together). I want the polygons from one file to be from one color and those frome the other from another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting multiple files into the same plot can be done by separating the plotting elements via comma. Check `help plot`.

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>   plot {<ranges>} <plot-element> {, <plot-element>, <plot-element>}
> ```

In order to increase the readability of the script and lengthy plot commands, you can introduce "linebreaks" with `\` being the very last character in the line (couldn't find the help keyword anymore for this, but I know it is somewhere hidden in help).

Have you tried:

```
plot  cell_files0(i) w filledcurves ls 1,  \
      cell_files1(i) w filledcurves ls 2
```

Comment: Thank you it worked (and especially thanks for the command help plot), do you know how to add edges to the polygons? Because I would still like to visualize the limits between my cell while here, cells of the same type are of the same color with no edge to differentiate between them.

Comment: @BilalBOTTÉ check `help filledcurves border`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, in case someone has the same problem as I, here is the code once it works:

```
N = 100
d = sqrt(2/sqrt(3))
h = sqrt(3)*d/2

start = 0000
stop = 1990

set terminal pngcairo rounded size 800,800

set xrange [0:d*sqrt(N)]
set yrange [0:h*sqrt(N)]

point_files(n) = sprintf('./PointFiles/points%06d.txt', n)
cell_files0(n) = sprintf('./Cellpop0Files/cells%06d.txt', n)
cell_files1(n) = sprintf('./Cellpop1Files/cells%06d.txt', n)

do for [i = start:stop:10] {
    outfile = sprintf('./Figures/figures%06d.png',i)
    set output outfile
    set border
    unset key
    plot cell_files0(i) with filledcurves fc "royalblue" fs solid 0.5 border lc    "black", \
     cell_files1(i) with filledcurves fc "yellow" fs solid 0.5 border lc "black"
}
```